# How to create a stored procedure in postgreSQL to insert new rows whilst handling errors and exceptions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, exception, error-handling, duplicates

I have a 'PLAYER' table in my database with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS local."Player"
(
    "Player_ID" integer NOT NULL,
    "Club_ID" integer NOT NULL,
    "Group_ID" integer NOT NULL,
    "First_Name" character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    "Last_Name" character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    "Goals_Scored" integer,
    "Yellow_Card_Count" integer,
    "Red_Card_Count" integer,
    PRIMARY KEY ("Player_ID")
);
```

I'd like to create a stored procedure to add new players with the relevant fields but I need it to raise an exception/error when a player's name is added but is already existing in the table, and when the field Player_ID is also inserted as a duplicate.

I am able to create a simple stored procedure to just add new players but when it comes to exception/error handling I struggle. This is my first time creating stored procedures so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create unique constraints (or indexes) on the columns that should never have duplicates. The let the caller deal with the exception that stems from trying to insert duplicates.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for replying, I can try adding unique constraints for Player_ID, First_Name, and Last_Name, then go from there. Would you be able to provide a structure for the exception clause that would apply in this situation?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will change all field names into lowercase to avoid using quote identifiers, thanks for the advice!